# sessionStorage & localStorage alternatives for XHTML 1.0

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-transitional

As someone who is new to JavaScript & front end development, I am curious to know if there is a relatively simple JavaScript technique that I can use to keep a variable during a visitor session for an XHTML 1.0 transitional page?

I would like to use sessionStorage or localStorage, however, due to infrastructure constraints  it is not an option to change the page type to HTML5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what your infrastructure constraints are, but is there any specific reason why you must use Transitional? Otherwise I'd suggest going with XHTML5.

Comment: Unfortunately the website shares a common infrastructure with 20+ other websites and as such we cant necessarily just change the doc type without testing all websites. As such was looking for something a little easier to implement.